# Caption shifted left with `\captionof` in a list environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, captions

I use the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package within a list environment. I would expect the caption to be centered with respect to the page, or to move right because of the indentation of the lists. However, **the caption is shifted to the left** (see example below, with four lists to exagerate the problem). How can this be fixed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldcaption\caption
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  Within a float:
  \oldcaption{Default \LaTeX's caption. OK.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  Within a float:
  \caption{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\caption}. OK.}
\end{figure}
\noindent Outside of a float:
\bgroup
\captionof{figure}{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\captionof}. OK.}
\egroup
\begin{itemize}
\item
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
      \begin{itemize}
      \item
        \begin{figure}[h]
          Within a float, within lists:
          \caption{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\caption}. OK.}
        \end{figure}
        \noindent
        Outside of a float, within lists:
        \bgroup
        \captionof{figure}{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\captionof}. Left shift.}
        \egroup
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the reason of this behavior, but if you put your `\captionof` inside a `\parbox` of width `\linewidth`

```
\parbox{\linewidth}{\captionof{figure}{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\captionof}. Left shift.}}
```

the caption is centered in the remaining line width, that is, it is right-shifted as expected:

[image]

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldcaption\caption
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  Within a float:
  \oldcaption{Default \LaTeX's caption. OK.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  Within a float:
  \caption{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\caption}. OK.}
\end{figure}
\noindent Outside of a float:
\bgroup
\captionof{figure}{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\captionof}. OK.}
\egroup
\begin{itemize}
\item
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
      \begin{itemize}
      \item
        \begin{figure}[h]
          Within a float, within lists:
          \caption{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\caption}. OK.}
        \end{figure}
        \noindent
        Outside of a float, within lists:

        \vspace*{\baselineskip}
        \parbox{\linewidth}{\captionof{figure}{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\captionof}. Left shift.}}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Also notice that the 4th caption is outside the list... That's probably why you don't encounter that strange behavior.

Comment: Perfect! Just note that in the `\par\vspace*{...}` before the `\parbox`, the glue should be `\abovecaptionskip` rather than `\baselineskip`.

Comment: @MichelFioc you're obviously right about `\abovecaptionskip` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have added a \centering at your last caption which seems to fix the problem, although it still doesn't line up with the other captions.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\let\oldcaption\caption
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  Within a float:
  \oldcaption{Default \LaTeX's caption. OK.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  Within a float:
  \caption{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\caption}. OK.}
\end{figure}
\noindent Outside of a float:
\bgroup
\captionof{figure}{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\captionof}. OK.}
\egroup
\begin{itemize}
\item
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
      \begin{itemize}
      \item
        \begin{figure}[h]
          Within a float, within lists:
          \caption{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\caption}. OK.}
        \end{figure}
        \noindent
        Outside of a float, within lists:
        \bgroup
        \centering\captionof{figure}{\textsc{Caption}'s \texttt{\string\captionof}. Left shift.}
        \egroup
      \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Is this a fix for your problem?

Comment: This centers the list, not the caption...

Comment: I seem to have misinterpreted the question, it seems @karlkoeller does provide a working MWE. If his answer fixes your problem, I suggest you accept his feedback as the answer.